# rotate the camera horizontally and vertically three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I have the following code that makes my camera rotate vertically when i press a key (this works great):

```
var cameraOrginX = 0, cameraOrginY = 0, cameraOrginZ = 0;
var cameraEndX = 0, cameraEndY = -707, cameraEndZ = 707;
var angle = 1;

function onDocumentKeyDown(event){
    var keyCode = event.which;
    console.log(keyCode);

    if(keyCode == 87 || keyCode == 83){
        if (keyCode == 87) {
            angle = 1;
            console.log("forward  " + angle);
        }
        else if (keyCode == 83) {
            angle = -1;
            console.log("backward  " + angle);
        }
    }
    if(keyCode == 68 || keyCode == 65){
        if (keyCode == 68) {
            angle = 1;
            console.log("right  " + angle);
        }
        else if (keyCode == 65) {
            angle = -1;
            console.log("left  " + angle);
        }
    }

    //rotate vertically
    var radiansVert = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var radiansHori = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;

    var cosTheta = Math.cos(radiansVert);
    var sinTheta = Math.sin(radiansVert);

    var aVert = cosTheta * (cameraEndY-cameraOrginY);
    var bVert = sinTheta * (cameraEndZ-cameraOrginZ);
    var cVert = sinTheta * (cameraEndY-cameraOrginY);
    var dVert = cosTheta * (cameraEndZ-cameraOrginZ);

    cameraEndY = aVert - bVert + cameraOrginY;
    cameraEndZ = cVert + dVert + cameraOrginZ; 

    camera.position.x = cameraOrginX + cameraEndX;
    camera.position.y = cameraOrginY + cameraEndY;
    camera.position.z = cameraOrginZ + cameraEndZ;
    //
}
```

But now i want to make my camera also rotate horizontally... i tried copy and pasting the code between the comments and changing the variable names so it would work on the x and y axis but that gave me some weird results what i was not really looking for ;) could someone give me a tip or point me in the right direction on how to do this? i am still learning and any help would be greatly appriciated :)

if there is more code needed to make my problem clear let me know i can also make a jsfiddle if you want!

Comment: How did you calculate `cameraEndX`?

Comment: what is `cameraEnd` anyway? is it the point you want the camera to orbit around?

Comment: ' cameraEnd' is the position of the camera